# Using the ( REST and Spatial Data Services ) inputs a location and distance from that location to search in India & other countries

Tags: bing, bing-maps

I am working on an application which includes bing map with following functionality

1. User inputs a location and distance from that location to search.
2. Bing Maps REST Services [Locations API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701715.aspx) is used to geocode the location.
3. Bing Spatial Data Services [Query API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg585126.aspx) is used to search for points of interest near the location.
4. The POI information is displayed and pushpins are added to the map.
   for this I used following code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh757509.aspx in my application which is working fine for  North America because `NAVTEQNA` data source contains information about points of interest (POIs) in North America.

Now if i replace `NAVTEQNA` with  `FourthCoffeeSample` which is provided http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg585133.aspx . this is also working fine for same area but not working for India & other countries including US also except of North America.

#### Note

If I am entering any address of any country the address is Geocoding using the REST Services, but it is not searching for points of interest (POI) using Spatial data Services. Searching for points of interest (POI) using Spatial data Services is working fine for North America.

Please suggest me how it will work for India & other countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAVTEQNA is a data source with only data in North America. NAVTEQEU has data for Europe. There is no data source in the Bing Spatial Data Services with POI for India. You can use the old Bing Maps SOAP Search Service which has NAVTEQ + other POI data and may include India. Also the Search Manager in the Bing Maps controls also has this same data.